# delete function of queue

Tags: c++, queue

I'm facing a problem with my queue delete function. Please have a look at the following code.

```
class queueType // public queueADT<Type>

{

public:

const queueType<Type>& operator=(const queueType<Type>&);

bool isEmptyQueue() const;

bool isFullQueue() const;

void initializeQueue(int);
void minusIo(int);

Type & front();

Type & back();

void addQueue(const Type& queueElement);
void addQueueFront(const Type& newElement);

void deleteQueue();

queueType(int queueSize = 100);

queueType(const queueType<Type>& otherQueue);

~queueType();

bool operator== (const queueType<Type>&);

bool operator!= (const queueType<Type>&);

void deleteBackOfQueue();

void printQueue();
void sort();

bool notin(Type f);

void shortest(int);

Type *list;
int count;
Type & any(int);

void deleteany();


private:

int maxQueueSize;


int queueFront;

int queueRear;

bool isEqual(const queueType<Type>&);

};
```

The below is given my delete queue and print functions.

```
  template<class Type>

  void queueType<Type>::deleteQueue()

  { 

  if (!isEmptyQueue())

   { 


    queueFront = ++queueFront % maxQueueSize;
    count--;

  }
 else
    cout << "Cannot remove from an empty queue" << endl;



 }
```

Following is the print function.
    template

```
void queueType<Type>::printQueue()

{

for (int i = 0; i<count; i++)

{

    cout << list[i];

}

}
```

I used it in my main function as following.

void main()
{

```
queueType<int> RQ;

RQ.addQueue(2);
RQ.addQueue(8);
RQ.addQueue(7);
RQ.addQueue(2);
RQ.addQueue(4);

RQ.printQueue();
cout << endl;

RQ.deleteQueue();
RQ.printQueue();

getchar();
```

}

It is showing the following result.

```
28724
2872
```

I don't understand why it is deleting from the end and not from the front. To me code seems fine. Please have a look and let me know.

Comment: Since your delete function does not modify "list" your print should not start from zero but from queueFront.

Comment: @Jonas how can I modify the list?

Comment: Our change: cout << list[i]; into cout << list[i+queueFront];

Comment: Modifying, or not modifying, list is essential to the core of your implementation. And thus, I cannot tell without the rest of your class.

Comment: @Jonas but 2 will remain in the list.I want to delete it. any idea?

Comment: @Jonas thanks for your help, how can I mark your answer ?

Comment: I posted an answer based on my comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your delete function does not modify "list" your print should not start from zero but from queueFront. An easy way to achieve this is by replacing:

```
cout << list[i];
```

with:

```
cout << list[i+queueFront];
```

In your printing function.
But you should look into modifying `list` in some way, while still keeping a pointer to the memory you have to `free`.

Comment: Add in case it is not clear, you accept an answer by clicking the checkmark next to the proper answer.